# Bash find value in array

Tags: bash

I used this function to find values in an array for a while but I'd like to improve it:

```
 # Checks if the first argument is found in the subsequent ones.

 function my_function_is_value_in() {

   local -r NEEDLE=$1
   local -ra HAYSTACK=( "${@:2}" )

   local value
   for value in "${HAYSTACK[@]}"; do
     [[ $value == "$NEEDLE" ]] && return 0
   done

   return 1

 }
```

I now think the assignment to the "parameter renaming for readability" array `HAYSTACK` is inefficient, especially for a "search" function, potentially run many times as so:

```
my_function_is_value_in coconut cherry coriander coconut cottage-cheese
```

Does Bash have an efficient way to do the above or is looping through `${@:2}` directly as efficient as this can get?

Compare/contrast with `perl`'s `grep( /pattern/ @array)`.. that's a dedicated function to do exactly this.

Comment: `perl's` grep function is not efficient for this task. It iterates through the entire array, even if the first element was a match. Never use perl's `grep` in boolean context, use `List::MoreUtils::any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get better results from this, but I've not done any measurements to demonstrate either way:

```
function my_function_is_value_in()
{
    local -r NEEDLE=$1
    shift
    local value
    for value in "$@"
    do
        [[ $value == "$NEEDLE" ]] && return 0
    done
    return 1
}
```

The thinking is that the shell doesn't need to make a copy of the array of arguments this way; that should speed things up.

Comment: Here an hopefully interesting question for you, Jonathan: are you sure `shift` does not perform a copy of the positional arguments? Could you prove it? `array.c` has a `array_shift` method that works on a null-terminated linked list but `builtins/shift.def` hints to copying to me (`dollar_vars[count] = dollar_vars[count + 1];`). Your take?

Comment: Hmmm... Q: Are you sure `shift` does not perform a copy of the positional arguments? A: Moderately. Q: Could you prove it? A: Not without scrutinizing shell source code.  However, there's no use for the old value of `$1` once it is shifted, and no reason to make a copy of `$2` et al.  Of course, function arguments are different from script arguments, but the concepts still apply.  I've not studied the `bash` code, and really don't have plans to do so at the moment.

Comment: The doubt came to me from looking at this: http://bashcookbook.com/bashinfo/source/bash-4.1/builtins/shift.def (`dollar_vars[count] = dollar_vars[count + 1];`) but, as you say, it's not important now.. Thanks for the answer, which I accepted! :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be faster than an explicit loop:

```
my_function_is_value_in ()
{
  [[ "${@:2}" =~ "$1" ]] && return 0 || return 1
}
```